# Stata: minimum and maximum within a 15 minute window, under certain conditions

Tags: stata

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
exec_minute   price        volume
13.43         96.125       1000
28.43056      94.5         2500
28.43056      96           2500
29.42889      96.068       500
29.42889      96.068       500
32.42028      96.953       1000
32.42056      96.953       1000
32.43278      96.042       1200
33.42639      95.917       1200
42.41667      96.042       4000
42.42139      96.042       300
48.45833      98.323295    11000
50.46028      97           300
50.46028      97           11000
50.46028      97           300
50.46305      97           11000
56.46333      95.51        2000
```

I want to aggregate all trades that occur within a 15 minute window and have  the same volume, take the max and min prices and then use these max and min prices for further calculation.

Can anybody help me tackle this? I've tried using 
    egen min_price=(price)

toegther with some if statements, but it appears to only work for the whole dataset.

Thanks in advance!
J

Answer (score 0):

`help egen` and `help by` are probably the places to start.

The way that I would go about this is:

1. Create a categorical variable that is a different value for each 15 minute window.
2. Use `egen` to create the minimum and maximum variables `by` the categorical variable and volume.

If you add some code that you tried to your question and still can't get what you want I'm happy to edit my answer to answer the coding part of the question

edit:

to update a bit based on your comment, you could use code like this to get an indicator variable that you can then use `by` and `egen` to get what (at least how I interpret) what you want

```
// generate variable for window indicator
gen window_indicator = .

// get the max value and divide by window length
sum exec_minute
local max = floor(`r(max)'/15)


// loop over values from 0 to max and replace window indicator 
// to be equal to the local ii for each section
forvalues ii = 0/`max' {
    replace window_indicator = `ii' if exec_minute> `ii'*15 & exec_minute< (`ii'+1)*15

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, Eric.
I know the egen and by functions, but using them in a code would define stiff 15 min windows, not moving ones (i.e. 1->15, 2->16 etc.). For that I would need 15 individual variables with groups and that's absolutely not practical. Sorry that I didn't make that clear in the original question. Best, J